# I get CORS error in python flask RESTApi when sending a request using angular

Tags: python, angular, flask

I have a python script which is a flask RESTApi:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

api = Flask(__name__)
CORS(api)

@api.route("/api/stopService", methods=['POST'])
def startService()
    return {
      "MSG": "OK"
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run(port=8000)
```

Now I want to make a request with angular using this code:

```js
this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/stopService', {}).subscribe((res: any) => {
    
});
```

It's just a simple button that when I click on, it triggers the request. but I get this error:
[image: error]

And if I click on the button again It's OK and I have the response.

Here is the flask log:
[image: log]

First line is when I get the CORS error, and the second and the third one is the OK response.

**Edit 1**
I changed my flask code to this but still no luck:

```py
from flask import Flask

api = Flask(__name__)

@api.route("/api/stopService", methods=['POST'])
def startService()
    return {
      "MSG": "OK"
    }

@api.after_request
def addHeaders(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run(port=8000)
```

Comment: Try to remove the empty object {} in your Angular post.

Comment: @MikeOne well that's required

Comment: @MikeOne, I replaced the empty object with null, and it got fixed. please send an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that angular runs on port 4200 and you try to do a call on port 8000. For the browser those are two different domains and therefore you get a cors error.

If you want to get it work on localhost, you have to add cors headers to the response in your python script:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: I'm using flask_cors

Comment: Try to add `@cross_origin()` below `@api.route`. According to documentation of flas_cors this should solve your problem

Comment: I did that, nothing changed